# Use the graph of Y=f(x) shown below to answer the following questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

https://www.flickr.com/photos/134404416@N03/shares/6p9h7f

[image]

I tried answering some of the questions as you can see in the picture link provided, but I just am not sure if my answers are even right.

**Edit**

Here is some of the text in the picture in case you don't want to go to the picture...

The picture shows $f(0)=1.5$

A - Does this function have a minimum or maximum value

B - Solve the equation $3f(x-2)+1=1$

C - Over which interval is the function increasing

D - How many inflection points does the function have?

E -  Evaluate ${(f(f(5))+f(0)})/{-3}$

F - In which of the following 3 intervals is the average rate of change negative?
$[0,3] - [0,4] - [0,5]$

Comment: Always good to retype the problem!

Comment: Stil... unclear and small pictures!

Comment: Are you allowed to find values such as f(2) directly from the curve?

Comment: The picture you provided is too small to read.  Please type up the work you did on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

The scan is a bit unclear, but it looks like the picture also suggests that $f(x) = 0$ for $x = 1$ and $x = 3$, and that $f(5) = 4$.
Using symmetry you also get $f(4) = 1.5$.

Also, note that you wrote the wrong formula for the average rate of change: it is
$$
\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}
$$
not $\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{b-a}$.

This is enough information to answer all the questions, at least if you know what an [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) is.

Comment: f(0) = 1.5, so f(x) is not equal (x-1)(x-3) as you suggested.

Comment: @EmmadKareem I never said that, nor suggested it. Three points uniquely determine a parabola with symmetry axis parallel to the $y$-axis. In particular, the one through $(0,1.5), (1,0)$, and $(3,0)$ has equation $y = 0.5 x^2-2 x+1.5$ (here's a link to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parabola+through+%280%2C1.5%29+%281%2C0%29+%283%2C0%29) in case you wish to check it out), and it's graph seems to be consistent with the one from the picture.

Comment: I assumed that since x=1 and x=3 are roots, then the function must be (x-1)(x-3) but apparently there is more than 1 second degree polynomial that  has the same roots! Thanks for the explanation. It would be nice to know how to generate all such polynomials that share the same roots then...I feel something is not quite right but it is 2 A.M. and I am not thinking straight.

Comment: @EmmadKareem Well, almost. You know that a parabola has equation $y = f(x)$ with $f$ a polynomial of degree $2$, and you want that both $x-1$ and $x-3$ divide $f(x)$ (i.e. you want $1$ and $3$ as roots), so all that's left is a constant. Indeed, all the parabolas through $(0,1),(0,3)$ have equation of the form $y = k(x-1)(x-3)$ for some $k \in \Bbb{R}$. Note that $k = 0$ allows you to account for the $x$-axis as a degenerate parabola. Finding a parabola through three generic points involves solving a system of linear equations (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parabola.html)).

Comment: Good explanation. I appreciate it.